# How can I write a query for each element of json_decode?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I posted a JSON array as a string from a volley request in Android, and I decode it with JSON decode. Here is my PHP code:

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
     //Getting values
     $courseList = $_POST['courseList'];

     $professor_ID = $_POST['Prof_ID'];

     $list = json_decode($courseList);

     print_r($list);
     require_once('dbConnect.php');

$sql = "select Stud_ID,student.f_Name,student.l_Name from student,course where course.S_ID = student.Stud_ID and course.P_ID in ($list)";
.
.
.
?>
```

And here is print_r($list) result:

```
 Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
)
```

Now, I want to write a query for each element of JSON decode, but it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

You can use foreach loop or implode

```
<?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  //Getting values 
 require_once('dbConnect.php');
 // i am assuming $con is your connection variable

 // its good practice to check against sql injection
 $courseList = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $_POST['courseList'] );
 $professor_ID = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $_POST['Prof_ID'] );

 $list = json_decode( $courseList );

 print_r( $list );

 // Assuming $list is 
 //   Array
 //  (
 //    [0] => 1
 //    [1] => 2
 //  )    

 foreach ( $list as $p_id ) {
   // prepare your query
   $sql = "select Stud_ID,student.f_Name,student.l_Name from student,course where course.S_ID = student.Stud_ID and course.P_ID = $p_id ";
   // execute and do other stuff
}

// or use implode
$pid = (implode(', ', $list);
$sql = "select Stud_ID,student.f_Name,student.l_Name from student,course where course.S_ID = student.Stud_ID and course.P_ID in $pid ";
// execute and do other stuff


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this code snippet, I've used the implode function to convert the $list array into a comma-separated string, then concatenate it with the SQL query string. This should work correctly with your SQL query.

```
$implodedList = implode(', ', $list);

$sql = "select Stud_ID,student.f_Name,student.l_Name from student,course where course.S_ID = student.Stud_ID and course.P_ID in ($implodedList)";
```